# segmentation fault in signal level

Tags: c

I have written a phone book and my person input like "name-number-type" and if the user give "_" or any other character that is not "-" as seperator the program will crash by seg. fault because i used strtok() to split input. Also if the user gives number that is not proper input like 1232414eree224, my program will crash again. So i just think that if i handle the seg. fault signal in os level may be i can fix this bug. I know that i can write a controller function but i am searching for a new way to deal with like that error. Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So i just think that if i handle the seg. fault signal in os level may
>   be i can fix this bug.

It does not seem like a good idea at all, a `SIGSEGV` handler ​​is not intended to ignore or try to fix the error, they are used to consistently exit your process, e.g. remove the used heap so that there are no memory leaks, to write in a log reporting the error ...

In addition, in the POSIX standard:

> The behavior of a process is undefined after it returns normally from
>   a signal-catching function for a [XSI] SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or
>   SIGSEGV signal that was not generated by kill(), [RTS] sigqueue(), or
>   raise().